# IGrouping, IEnumerable and Pairs

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I am having some trouble. I am supposed to implement a definition of `GroupBy`.
I am not sure how to group the values in Pairs, can someone help me? Can't use LINQ

Definition of Pair:

```
class Pair<K, V> {
    public Pair(K key, V value) {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }
    public K Key { get; set; }
    public V Value { get; set; }
}
```

main:

```
string[] src = { "ola", "super", "isel", "ole", "mane", "xpto", "aliba" };
foreach (Pair<int, IEnumerable<string>> pair in src.GroupBy(s => s.Length))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, string.Join(", ", pair.Value));
}
```

Output

```
/**
* Output:
* 3: ola, ole
* 5: super, aliba
* 4: isel, mane, xpto
*/
```

Comment: `GroupBy` won't return `Pair<V, L>`. It's of type `System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable<string, int, string>`.

Answer (score 2):

To make a `Pair<int, IEnumerable<string>>` from an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>` you´ll need this:

```
foreach (Pair<int, IEnumerable<string>> pair in src.GroupBy(s => s.Length)
    .Select(x => new Pair<int, IEnumerable<string>>(x.Key, x.ToList()))
)
```

But I´m not sure why anyone should use this.

Quite easier to use is just this:

```
foreach (var pair in src.GroupBy(s => s.Length))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, string.Join(", ", pair.ToList()));
}
```

This way you dn´t even need your `Pair`-class.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with using a `Dictionary<k,v>`?

Comment: @Rahul It´ll put the entire collection into memory for instance, which is a bad idea when the collection is big. Second why should you make a dictionary at all? It does not add any value to iterate every group on its own.

Comment: Your interpretation is wrong ... comment was meant for OP and not you bro. I meant use a dictionary instead `Pair<int, IEnumerable<string>>`

Comment: @Rahul Okay, I see. However to avoid such confusion better place thi comment on the actual question or adress OP directly.

Answer (score 0):

The code after the `GroupBy` (i.e. the `Select`) will project the data into the `Pair` class that you are trying to use.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        class Pair<K, V>
        {
            public Pair(K key, V value)
            {
                Key = key;
                Value = value;
            }
            public K Key { get; set; }
            public V Value { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] src = { "ola", "super", "isel", "ole", "mane", "xpto", "aliba" };
            var pairs = src.GroupBy(s => s.Length)
                .Select(@group => new Pair<int, IEnumerable<string>>(@group.Key, @group));

            foreach (var pair in pairs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, string.Join(", ", pair.Value));
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```